# How to add custom class in to each day in Calendar widget with KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui

As the title states, how do I add a custom class in to each day in the Calendar Widget with KendoUI

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create Calendar from div HTML element
    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();
});
```

How do I add class "check_day" to each day in the calendar.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [kendo template](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/template.html) maybe ?

For example, try this in their demo page

```
$("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
    month: {
        // template for dates in month view
        content: '<div class="check_day"> #: data.value #</div>'
    },
    footer: false
});
```